# How can I convert SVG images to Windows ICO or Mac ICN icons?

Tags: windows, macos, svg, icons

I'd like to convert svg icons to windows icons and mac icons. A free option would be the best.

Comment: Probably a better question for superuser.com

Comment: Better tell people what's your platform.

Comment: Agreed re: platform.  As a programmer, you can do this on a mac with the platform APIs.

Comment: @Abizern - not unless he wants to do it programmatically.
@user388624 - please clarify your question so that people can assist.

Comment: @Saajid Ismail – Since the OP mentioned the price, it's a reasonable assumption that a software tool is required rather than code snippets.

Answer (score 6):

To expand on @Colonel Panic's original answer, which I feel is best, on a Mac you'll need to first install ImageMagick's CLI tools with:

```
brew install imagemagick
```

This provides the `convert` command, which can then be used to create a valid Mac ICO from an SVG. You'll need to resize the SVG to a valid ICO size for the OS. This is the command I ended up using to do this myself:

```
convert icon.svg -resize 256x256 icon.ico
```

ImageMagick is well documented in the following places:

- [Convert Command Docs](https://imagemagick.org/script/convert.php)
- [Magick Command Docs](https://imagemagick.org/script/command-line-processing.php)

Answer (score 5):

There's a free online tool available for this purpose: http://iconverticons.com/

Comment: This is an ancient post, but can you expand your answer a bit? Just pointing to a product or service doesn't really explain how to accomplish the solution. It's better to include some instructions or screenshots, or at least describe what makes this a good solution. Good guidance on recommending software or services here: http://meta.superuser.com/questions/5329/how-do-i-recommend-software-in-my-answers.  Thanks.

Comment: Looks like shilling for own product.

Comment: This is not a free online tool.

Answer (score 5):

The [gimp](http://www.gimp.org/) editor can open svg files and save them as ico files. From http://www.gimp.org/features/:

> File Formats
>
> The file format support ranges from
>   the common likes of JPEG (JFIF), GIF,
>   PNG, TIFF to special use formats such
>   as the multi-resolution and
>   multi-color-depth Windows icon files.

Answer (score 3):

Your answer to all image conversion problems http://www.imagemagick.org

Try:

```
 convert in.svg out.ico
```

Comment: This is an ancient post, but can you expand your answer a bit? Just pointing to a product doesn't really explain how to accomplish the solution. It's better to include some instructions on how to use the product to solve the problem, or at least describe what makes the product a good solution. Good guidance on recommending software here: http://meta.superuser.com/questions/5329/how-do-i-recommend-software-in-my-answers.  Thanks.

Answer (score 1):

I *exported* my images to PNG with [Inkscape](http://inkscape.org), then I used a commercial Windows program [IcoFX](http://icofx.ro) that has a good editor.

Comment: Can you expand your answer a little with more detail as to how to accomplish your solution?  Thanks.

Answer (score 0):

All answers here mention how to convert to .ico but not how to convert to .icns, here is an open source tool for just that: https://github.com/JackMordaunt/icns

Install with homebrew:

```
brew tap jackmordaunt/homebrew-tap # Ensure tap is added first.
brew install icnsify
```

Usage:

```
icnsify -i icon.png -o icon.icns
icnsify -i icon.icns -o icon.png
```

Comment: Your answer could be improved with additional supporting information. Please [edit] to add further details, such as citations or documentation, so that others can confirm that your answer is correct. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).

Comment: Sorry bot, but my answer is better than your thinking abilities.